# Need Explanation about Array.prototype.map and map.call( ), how this is working?

Tags: javascript, array-map

```
let Map = Array.prototype.map
let strResult = Map.call("Muhammad asif", (x) => {
    return x.charCodeAt(0);
})
console.log(strResult)
```

What is the relation between call and map and how is its process? why charCodeAt(0) used here?

Comment: Have you read [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Yeah, I know about this method @jabaa, but I can't understand map.call, and what is charCodeAt

Comment: You know about `Function.prototype.call` but you can't understand `Map.call`? That makes no sense. It's the same. `Map` is a function. `Map.call` is the function `Function.prototype.call` that is defined in the prototype of all functions. You can read about [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

Comment: You can search for `mdn ` + "search term" in your favorite search engine for all questions about JavaScript, e.g. `mdn charCodeAt`, `mdn call`, `mdn map`. Some browsers even support to add MDN as internal search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. What is the relation between `call` and `map`?

- As @jabaa said in the comments section, `map` is a function. `call` also a function.
- `map` is a part of `Array` object, and `call` is a part of `Function` object.
- It means,

  - you should use `map` on an array. For example: `[1, 2, 3].map()`,
  - and use `call` on a function. For example: `myFunction.call()`

---

> 2. How is its process?

`Array.prototype.map` is a function that you put on a variable called `Map`. You can't just use it like a normal function, because it is designer to be used with an array. You can use it like this:

```
const myArray = [1, 2, 3]
myArray.Map = Map // put your `Map` variable into a real array
myArray.Map(number => console.log(number))
```

OR

```
Map.call("your array or iterable things goes here", (itemInArray) => {console.log(itemInArray)});
/* first parameter of `call` will be used as `this`. `this` in `Array.prototype.map` means an array. CMIIW */
```

Which is the same as:

```
const myString = "your array or iterable things goes here"
for(let index = 0; index < myString.length; index++){
  const itemInArray = myString[index]
  console.log(itemInArray)
}
```

---

> 3. Why `charCodeAt(0)` used here?

I don't know. That is your code, and the one who should answer this question is yourself. `charCodeAt` is not a required function for `map` or `call` to works. FYI, `charCodeAt` is also a function that [returns an integer between 0 and 65535 representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt). So,

```
"abc".charCodeAt(0) // will show UTF-16 representation of the 0th character of "abc"
"abc".charCodeAt(1) // will show UTF-16 representation of the 1st character of "abc"
"abc".charCodeAt(2) // will show UTF-16 representation of the 2nd character of "abc"
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find some explanation https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/explain-array-prototype-map-call/165936/7

With this approach, you can use `map` function on string as it was an array.

`charCodeAt` is the function called on each element of the given string. It returns the Unicode representation (a number) of passed character. You can pass any other string-accepting function istead of it.

For example:

```
let Map = Array.prototype.map
let strResult = Map.call("Muhammad asif", (x) => {
    return x + x
});
console.log(strResult)
```

will result with
["MM", "uu", "hh", "aa", "mm", "mm", "aa", "dd", "  ", "aa", "ss", "ii", "ff"]